# Why does an html element created and inserted on a click event persists for subsequents renderings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

An span element is created and inserted inside the clicked element e.g. in the image the 10th square was clicked. I want that element to stay marked just for that month, the problem is that when I go to other month clicking "Next", the 10th day is marked as well.

[image]

Here is the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-http-g8up5?file=/src/components/Test.js
App.js:

```
import Test from "./components/Test";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Test />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Test.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./css/Calendar.css";
function Test() {
  const [month, setMes] = useState(0);
  const daysMonth =
    (Date.UTC(2021, month + 1) - Date.UTC(2021, month)) / 1000 / 3600 / 24;
  const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"];
  function nextMonth() {
    setMes(month + 1);
  }
  function prevMonth() {
    setMes(month - 1);
  }

  function addElement(e) {
    let span = document.createElement("span");
    span.style.background = "red";
    span.style.borderRadius = "50px";
    span.appendChild(document.createTextNode("X"));
    e.target.appendChild(span);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{months[month]}</h2>
      <div className="grid">
        {[...Array(daysMonth)].map((e, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={i} className="dayStyle" onClick={addElement}>
              {i + 1}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <button onClick={prevMonth} disabled={month <= 0 ? true : false}>
        Previous
      </button>
      <button onClick={nextMonth} disabled={month >= 5 ? true : false}>
        Next
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

Calendar.css:

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 80px);
  gap: 1px;
}
.dayStyle {
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: It may be related to the array index being used as React key. When you map the days of the month you are using an array index. The array indices will more or less be the same month-to-month. The index for Jan 10th will be the same for Dec 10th and Feb 10th.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you use the array index as the React key. When you map the days of the month the array indices will more or less be the same month-to-month. The index for Jan 10th will be the same for Dec 10th and Feb 10th.

The solution is to make the React keys unique month-to-month: `` key={`${month}-${i}`} ``

```
{[...Array(daysMonth)].map((e, i) => {
  return (
    <div
      key={`${month}-${i}`}
      className="dayStyle"
      onClick={addElement}
    >
      {i + 1}
    </div>
  );
})}
```

## Demo

[image: Edit why-does-an-html-element-created-and-inserted-on-a-click-event-persists-for-subs]

Comment: Thank's but, do you have any suggestion for the mark to stay there when I go back to that month?

Comment: @user2495207 Gah, I suspected that question was coming. You'll need to maintain that in state (and possibly persist to localStorage) somewhere. To be honest, that's what you should be doing anyway, instead of mutating the DOM you should update state and derive the DOM from that state. Since you weren't keeping these in state previously I didn't address that aspect in regards to the specific issue you asked about. (out-of-scope)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update daysMonth variable when you switch months.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue as `daysMonth` is computed upon every render, regardless of `month` value.

Comment: Yeah your right but to me it doesn't seem like the added element is ever updated on click right? I'm not trying to argue :)

Comment: Well, it's certainly updated, but since `appendChild` is a direct DOM manipulation (i.e. outside of React), and that there's no mapped component with state/props and the React key remains the same React bails on flushing any changes to the DOM for that mapped element. From React's perspective nothing changed so it doesn't update the DOM.

Comment: Oh you are right by all means I know nothing almost. 
your answer above mine certainly works. My low reputation prevents me from commenting on it :(